# Debug FeatureActivated() in SharePoint WebForms

Tags: c#, debugging, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-debugging, sharepoint-deployment

Is it possible to debug FeatureActivated?

I am doing:

1. Deploy ->
2. Set Breakpoint in the public override void FeatureActivated ->
3. Attach the process to the debugger ->
4. refresh.

This doesn't work because the app has already been deployed and activated.

How do I tell it to insta-stop and let me walk through the activation process.

Answer (score 1):

deploy >> set break point >> attach process to debugger
then goto site action >> site settings >> manager site features >> deactivate feature and then activate it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the line to your code:

`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`

Once the feature is activated, you will see Debug popup dialog and connect to the process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

1. Disable auto-activation at deploy time : Your SharePoint project > Properties > SharePoint > "Current deployement configuration" > Set "none"
2. Deploy
3. Attach the debugger : Debug > Attach process > select w3wp.exe
4. Set some breakpoints
5. Activate manually your feature : Site Settings > Site collection feature (if the feature's scope is site)